# Regular Expression not validating the complete email address

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I've following regular expression:
**([A-Za-z0-9.-])*\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63})(.([A-Za-z]{2,6}))*** and validate **test@gamil.com** and **test@gamil** as well. While it must validate **test@gmail.com** and the email with the sub-domain.

Any help is there to make me correct.

Comment: I would have a go at an already existing email regex script, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). This is a complicated solution, and writing a custom one may leave some email addresses out that are valid.

Comment: Can you please check your regular expression? It looks to me like you are missing a + before \@. Also, did you mean to escape the .? If you don't, the . will match any character, and that may be your problem. (But I agree with Danbopes' comment: don't roll your own email regular expression.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  /^([A-Za-z0-9.-])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63})(\.([A-Za-z]{2,6}))$/
```

1) The first `^` and last `$` ensure that the whole string is matched

2) You neet a `+` before the `\@` to match the whole name, not just its last character

3) while you do not require a `\` before the `@` character you DO need one before the `.`

But as mentioned in the comments you would be better served finding a pre-built one on the web.

Answer (score 0):

1. You tried to match only **one** character before `@` sign, but you need to ensure that there is **at least one** character

   ([A-Za-z0-9.-])+
2. You missed to escape the `.` character at the final part of email (.com, .net, .xyz), also add the `+` modifier to accept both domains and sub-domains

   (.([A-Za-z]{2,6}))+

Finally, it should be something like this

```
([A-Za-z0-9.-])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63})(\.([A-Za-z]{2,6}))+
```

**See updated** [regex](https://regex101.com/r/nU8fW2/2)

Comment: I don't want the regular expression return true for test@gmail also I want test@gmail.com and test@uae.gov.pk must also be validated by the regular repression.

Comment: It should now neglects `test@gmail` and accepts `test@gmail.com` and `test@uae.gov.pk`

Answer (score 0):

I done with this. here in the following is the regular expression.

```
([A-Za-z0-9.-])*\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63})(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,6})
```

It validates the following kinda email address:

```
hello@gmail.com
he_llo@worl.d.com
hel.l-o@wor-ld.museum
h1ello@123.com
hello@world.com.pk
```

Thank You all for your kinda help.